# what's wrong with this program

Tags: java, while-loop

I've a code snippet:

```
class WhileTest
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        int x=12;
        while(x<13)
        {
            x--;
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is: `2147483647`

Why so?

[Code on ideone](http://ideone.com/xz29p6)

Comment: but I've used `println(x)`. Why these is no new line?

Comment: `x` wraps around at 0, becomes negative, and the loop finally stops when `x` becomes positive again at 0x7FFFFFFF (2147483647, which is >= 13).

Comment: can anybody give it a good title?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Your question or the result? Is this for an assignment or a test?

Comment: @Daniel: for question, a good title. No, its not a test. Actually I'd not thought of the situation of overflow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x` is decremented and then underflows reaching [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Answer (score 1):

Note that x = 12, and you keep subtracting. This results in x *always* being less than 13. That is until Integer Overflow occurs (when x gets to the lowest possible int (Integer.MIN_VALUE)), and the number wraps around to the maximum possible integer (Integer.MAX_VALUE) which is greater than 13 and the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

you decrease `x` each iteration.

when `x = -2147483648` (which is the [MIN_VALUE of Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE))
the next step of `x--` will set `x = +2147483647` (which is the [MAX_VALUE of Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)) because of the overflow (or underflow, however you call it).

and since `2147483647 < 13 = false` you will see the `println`

Comment: int x=-2147483647;
        x--;
        System.out.println(x); For this piece of code i received output as `-2147483648`. Why this is not `+2147483647`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo! integer min = -2147483648 of course. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration reduces the size of x, so theoretically x will never be greater than or equal to 13, right?

Sure, if ints behave just like integers. But they don't. Int's have a maximum and minimum size, because of how they stored in your computer. In Java, an int is a 32-bit signed number; an int's maximum size is 2^31-1; it's minimum size is -2^31.

What happens when x is the minimum size, -2^31, in that loop? -2^31 - 1  < 13, so why does the loop condition fail? That number can't be represented by an int. The way ints behave is that they wrap around.

```
int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // x = -2^31
x--;
x == Integer.MAX_VALUE; //True. x == 2^31-1
```

2^21 - 1 is larger than 13, and the loop condition fails. The print statement is run when x is Integer.MAX_VALUE. And what is the value of 2^31 - 1? 
2147483647

Answer (score 0):

The int value goes to Integer.MIN_VALUE, underflows and goes to Integer.MAX_VALUE which is what you're seeing.