# Why int variable value is set to Integer.MAX_VALUE when it was at Integer.MIN_VALUE and decremented

Tags: java, integer, operators

After going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893125/whats-wrong-with-this-program/18893190?noredirect=1#comment27887354_18893190) question, i had one another in my mind. 
Question: Why an integer variable value is set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

eg.

```
int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
x--;
if (x == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    System.out.println("Why....");
}
```

There must be some reason that is why this behavior implemented explicitly, otherwise throwing an `Exception` would be a better idea. I could not find/locate this behavior in JLS.

Comment: Because it's like this in every other language?

Comment: I assume because creating an exception object and throwing has performance associated with it

Comment: @PradeepSimha I don't think performance would be their major concern, as this is rare case, plus functionality can't be compromised over performance. We already have lot of Exceptions in java.

Comment: @Doorknob Not necessarily every other language, but the processor architecture itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2

"The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any way."

Answer (score 3):

Because of underflow. Computers have worked like this for years, throwing an Exception would be a horrible idea here.

Comment: But throwing an Exception would be a bad idea, what would be side-effects if `IntegerValueUnderFlowException` would be implemented in place of assigning mathematically as well as logically wrong value.

Comment: @GauravGupta The processor works like this too. Granted, it does set flags indicating that underflow occurred, but it's not an error such as dividing by zero.